# How do I add the results of work-items in a work-group in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I'm calling the kernel below with GlobalWorkSize `64 4 1` and WorkGroupSize `1 4 1` with the argument `output` initialized to zeros.

```
__kernel void kernelB(__global unsigned int * output) 
{
  uint gid0 = get_global_id(0);
  uint gid1 = get_global_id(1);

  output[gid0] += gid1;
}
```

I'm expecting `6 6 6 6 ...` as the sum of the `gid1`'s (0 + 1 + 2 + 3). Instead I get `3 3 3 3 ...` Is there a way to get this functionality? In general I need the sum of the results of each work-item in a work group.

EDIT: It seems it must be said, I'd like to solve this problem without atomics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use local memory to store the output from all work items. After the work items are done their computation, you sum the results with an accumulation step.

```
__kernel void kernelB(__global unsigned int * output) 
{
  uint item_id = get_local_id(0);
  uint group_id = get_group_id(0);

  //memory size is hard-coded to the expected work group size for this example
  local unsigned int result[4];

  //the computation
  result[item_id] = item_id % 3;

  //wait for all items to write to result
  barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

  //simple O(n) reduction using the first work item in the group
  if(local_id == 0){
    for(int i=1;i<4;i++){
      result[0] += result[i];
    }
    output[group_id] = result[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, when working with a lot more than 4 threads in the local workgroup, the OP should consider using parallel reduction for accumulating all of the results.

Comment: I used a method similar to the accepted answer, i.e. having one work-item sum and write the results of the work group. Per the previous comment, are there any links to an introduction to the parallel reduction method?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple work items are accessing elements of `global` simultaneously and the result is undefined. You need to use atomic operations or write unique location per work item.

Comment: That seems to explain why the example code does not work as expected. However, atomics are not an option and writing to a unique location is necessary (it seems) but not sufficient to solve the problem, i.e. How do I get the sum?

Comment: Re-write your kernel so each work item is responsible for a single output, and gather whatever input data you need in order to do that. In this example, write a 1D kernel with a global size of 64.